Need help understanding top-left rasterization rule
I need help in understanding top-left rasterization rule. It sounds simple, but I have trouble understanding certain example cases.
Why one triangle has its corner pixel filled but other doesn't? (outlined in magenta)
The same question for ones outlined in cyan. I get it that rightmost one is "top", so it's filled, but shouldn't the other one also be filled since it's "left"?


related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/rasterization-rules

I just had the same question referring to the same material as you; could it be that the negation is in place here?
"A pixel is considered inside if it is not on the bottom or right edge." (?)
see Hecker97 :
"We will define what’s called a top-left fill convention. Top-left refers to the
tie breaking rule used when the edge of a polygon lands exactly on a pixel center; if the edge is a top or a left edge, the pixel is in the polygon, if it’s a right or a bottom edge, the pixel is considered out."

It looks like corner points are generally not included, except when top/left or left/left edges meet. In D3D11 - 3.4.2.1 Top-Left Rule is written: "Top-Left Rule: If a sample location falls exactly on the edge of a triangle, the sample is inside the triangle if the edge is a "top" edge or a "left" edge. If two edges from the same triangle touch the pixel center, then if both edges are "top" or "left" then the sample is inside the triangle."

wikipedia has it in a way that might be the same: "One set of such rules is called a top-left rule, which states that a pixel is rasterized if and only if 1. its center lies completely inside the triangle. Or 2. its center lies exactly on the triangle edge (or multiple edges in case of corners) that is (or, in case of corners, all are) either top or left edge." although this formulation misses the top-edge-meets-left-edge corner I guess

The answer is in the poorly worded rule: "If two edges from the same triangle touch the pixel center, then if both edges are "top" or "left" then the sample is inside the triangle."
That means that corners are, by default, NOT drawn unless the segments forming it are "top and left" or "left and left".  (Top and top isn't possible as that would make a degenerate triangle).
Your left-most magenta point is a corner for a left and bottom segment--so, not drawn.
Your right-most magenta point is a corner for two left segments on the upper triangle--so, drawn.
Your upper-most cyan point is a corner for a left and a right segment--so, not drawn.
Your lower-most cyan point is a corner for a left and a top segment--so, drawn.
Do be careful, though.  You will note that the diagram does not include Y-coordinate direction (presumably on purpose) as that can muddy what the test for "top" is.
Hope this helps.
